Back button doesn't bring me back to Search Results page in Google Chrome 
Preamble
I had experience using Chrome for many years, but last two years I was on Yandex Browser. Now it's a return of the prodigal son back to Chrome, but there is a nuance...
Problem description
In Yandex I was using Google Search (as I do in Chrome) with "Open each search result in a new tab" (or something called like this) turned on. So, when I click on search result, it opens in a new tab and the Back Button is active. If I press it (via mouse or UI, doesn't matter) I get back to Search Results page. In Chrome I have similar setup, but Back Button is not active after opening any search result. It's so annoying, because I'm used to this ability and thought that is a default feature.
Expected behavior
So, I wanna be able to get back to Search Results page by clicking the Back Button after opening any search result.

How it looks like in Yandex
How it looks like in Chrome


Did it open a new tab? If so, pressing Ctl/Cmd+W will close the tab. Regardless, in order for a better answer to come from it, you should add more details such as- what did you try to fix it? what is the screenshot? Please edit to reflect the question rules on the help desk.

This is a common behavior in mobile browsers, but I can't find any discussion of how to get it in Chrome (besides a Reddit thread from 11 years ago with no helpful responses).

Search engines have options you can set to prefer opening results in new tabs. In desktop browsers, the back button does not close tabs. In Android, the back button is "hybrid" in a sense and as it controls both the browser Back AND "previous window" it will behave more consistently. Check your search engine settings to make sure you're not set to open a new tab or window.
